# dane (TLSA) validation java

Tags: java, android, dnssec, dane

I need to validate the DANE certificate from random websites.

I have tried https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html (The Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs for Java) and there is an example that goes near to what I need: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/cert/test/DANETest.java but I don't understund from where they take the randomCert and what is comparing in the second if.